# When I am running my Spring Boot application, I am getting the below error. I am using spring boot version 2.3.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlets

Spring Boot application error! When I am running my Spring Boot application, I am getting the below error. I am using spring boot version 2.3.1

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:334) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.adapt(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:446) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.getValue(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:369) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.asMap(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:284)
```

my pom.xml file is given below
I have tried to add dependencies but it's not working

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mani.restws</groupId>
    <artifactId>restws</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>restws</name>
    <description>Patient REST Services</description>
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.11</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
 <!--    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version> -->
</dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>       
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>  
</project>
```

Comment: Can you show your pom.xml or build.gradle?

Comment: Hey @AndrewSulyz I have added my pom.xml

Comment: @AndrewSulyz I have added that dependency but facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case problem in this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.11</version>
</dependency>
```

You can change version for this and add hibernate-validator

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That did the trick!